# Game of Nim Logic Error

Tags: java, error-handling, logic

I'm trying to make a game of nim at school, unfortunately i get a different output from what my desired output is; here is my code.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Nim2 {
    private static int numStonesLeft;

        /**
         */
     /**
      * The computerTurn method chooses a random number from 1 to 3 if
      * numStonesLeft is greater than or equal to 3, otherwise chooses a random
      * number from 1 to numStonesLeft.
      * 
      * Then decrements numStonesLeft appropriately and prints the turn.
      */
     public static void computerTurn() {
         int stonesChosen = (int) (Math.random() * 16) + 15;

         numStonesLeft -= stonesChosen;
         System.out.println("\nI took " + stonesChosen + " stones.");
         System.out.println("There are " + numStonesLeft + " stones left.");
     }

     /**
      * The playerTurn method prompts the user for a valid number of stones to
      * choose and reads an int value from the user and will repeat this action
      * while the user input is invalid. (i.e. user must choose 1, 2 or 3 AND
      * their choice must be less than or equal to numStonesLeft.)
      * 
      * Also decrements numStonesLeft appropriately and prints the turn.
      */
     public static void playerTurn() {
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Number of stones you take this turn:");
         int stonesChosen = 0;
         stonesChosen = input.nextInt();

         while (stonesChosen > 3 || stonesChosen < 1) {
             ;
             System.out.println("That is an invalid number of stones.");
             stonesChosen = input.nextInt();
         }

         if (stonesChosen <= 3 || stonesChosen >= 1)
             ;
         {
             System.out.println("\nYou took " + stonesChosen + " stones.");
             System.out.println("There are " + (numStonesLeft - stonesChosen)
                     + " stones left.");
         }
         stonesChosen = input.nextInt();

     }

     public void gameEnded() {          
            boolean over = false;


            }
     }
```

different client code

```
public class TestNim2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Nim2 nim = new Nim2();
         int numStonesLeft = (int) (Math.random() * 16) + 15;
        System.out.println("This is the Game of nim.");
        System.out.println("There is a pile of " + numStonesLeft
                + " stones between us.");
        System.out.println("We alternate taking either 1,2 or 3 stones.");
        System.out.println("The person who takes the last stone loses");

        // Write a loop to alternate computerTurn() and playerTurn()
        // checking after each turn see if there is a winner to print
        // and to break the loop ... then output the winner


            nim.playerTurn();
            nim.computerTurn();
        }
}
```

**The output i get is**

> Number of stones you take this turn: 2
>
> You took 2 stones. There are -2 stones left. 3
>
> I took 16 stones. There are -16 stones left.

**My desired output is supposed to be similar to something like this**

> You took 2 stones. There are 18 stones left //random number of 20
>
> I took 3 stones There are 15 stones left

Comment: How are you getting the output ? Your code does NOT even compile

Comment: I can see at least 2 problems: 1) In both computerTurn() and playerTurn(), you haven't check that `numStonesLeft >= stonesChosen`  so there is negative number appear  

2) in playerTurn(), you have not deduct the numStonesLeft from the stonsChosen

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few problems:

- You don't initialize `numStonesLeft`.
- You forgot `numStonesLeft -= stonesChosen;` in the player turn.
- No check for `numStonesLeft >= 0` after deduction.
- Putting a semicolon after the `if` is probably parsed in a way that the following scope is executed unconditionally. Stop putting random semicolons at the beginning of lines.
- Superfluous `stonesChosen = input.nextInt();` in player turn.